# Rocket's path is graphed by function $f(x) = x^3 - 8x$

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

A rocket's path is graphed by the function $f(x) = x^3 - 8x$, where $x$ refers to time after launch (s). At what point after its launch would you release its thrusters in order for its tangent path to pass through the point $(4,0)?$

Comment: And textbook writers (or whoever wrote this problem) come up with yet another way to make a math problem more "relevant" to the real world by making it almost completely divorced from reality. (The writer of the problem would have flunked freshman physics.) I suppose this problem is just a weird way of saying find a tangent line through the point $(4,0),$ and the answer is the $x$ coordinate of the tangent point on the curve.

Comment: What does f(x) represent?

Comment: Kinda strange rocket as it flies (?) below ground between $0$ and $\sqrt8$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe it could be a rocket which starts from a cliff! Or it could be interpreted as an 2D path in horizontal plane. The rocket is only an example to formulate the problem, the set up is very clear to me.

Comment: Or we just change the relation to the so called reality and consider the path of a mole instead of a rocket.

Comment: [Here are some tips on how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Comment: @AustinLandry Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use different symbols $x$ for distance and $t$ for time

If the rocket is headed only to look at the point $(4,0)$ ( reaching there is another matter due to a different trajectory )..

match the slope of cubic's derivative to slope at the required point

$$\dfrac{(x^3-8x)-0}{x-4}= 3 x^2-8$$

simplify /solve cubic (edit: with simplification error corrected )

$$(x-2)(x^2+8)=0, \rightarrow x =2 $$

is the time for it to look at $(4,0),$ and fire the rocket imparting a very high velocity like a laser ray.

Comment: Note that I didn't give the full solution in order to make find it to the asker, now I'm forced to give the full solution. Note also that your calculation is wrong.

Comment: At that time the rocket’s height is negative, just to mention.

Comment: @gimusi thanks, corrected my arithmetic error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the position is $(x,f(x))$

- consider a generic point $P(x,f(x))$ on the path
- set the condition for which $f'(x)$ is equal to the slope $PQ$ with $Q=(4,0)$

that is

$$\dfrac{(x^3-8x)-0}{x-4}= 3 x^2-8 \iff x^3-8x=3x^3-8x-12x^2+32 \iff2x^3-12x^2+32=0$$

from which we obtain $x=2$.

Comment: But the equation does not have a variable representing position of the rocket.

Comment: @VishaalSelvaraj I'm assuming that the position is (x,f(x)), I add this point in the hint